# Как сделать скрипт на сайте чтобы каждые 10 секунд изменялся цвет таблицы

Tags: html, javascript

Собственно, мне нужно, чтобы каждые 10 секунд менялся цвет таблицы.

Comment: @heks, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1):

Весь код не читал, такое в jsfiddle нужно оформлять.

А по вопросу вам нужно

1. для изменения цвета найти элемент - $('#table').css('color','#FF0000')
2. используя setInterval дергать функцию перекрашивания